# Call subroutine invalid recursive self-reference

Tags: fortran, call, gfortran, subroutine

I'm trying to compute the length of bond chains for the COMMON neighbours using a subroutine, but I get the error

> `FOR3414: invalid recursive self-reference to BOND detected between CALL and BOND`.

This below is the subroutine where I get the error:

```
SUBROUTINE bond (kk)
    
!   local variables 
    parameter     (natmax=50000,nvoisin_com_max=50,max_chain=100)
    parameter     (nvoisin_max=50,ibond_max=100)

    integer       ia,ja,kk,jj,nvoisin_com,nb,nc,index 
    integer       length (max_chain),pvoisin_com(nvoisin_com_max)
    integer       visit(nvoisin_com_max)
                
    integer       n_voisin(natmax),pvoisin(natmax,nvoisin_max)  
    logical       voisin_logic

!   COMMON variables    
    COMMON /e1/ n_voisin
    COMMON /e2/ pvoisin 
    COMMON /e3/ nvoisin_com,pvoisin_com
    COMMON /e4/ length,visit
    COMMON /e5/ nb,nc
    
    index = 0
    visit (kk) = 1
    
!   if index = 0 at the end, before return a new chain is added 
!   (the atoms is the end of a chain)

    ia = pvoisin_com (kk)
    do jj = 1, nvoisin_com
    
       if (kk.eq.jj) cycle
       if (visit(jj).eq.1) cycle
              
       ja = pvoisin_com (jj)           
       call voisin (ia,ja,voisin_logic)  
         
       if (voisin_logic) then        
         nb = nb + 1
         index = 1
         call bond (jj)
       endif
      
    enddo
    
    if (index.eq.0) then   
         nc = nc + 1
         length(nc) = nb
    endif
    
    nb = nb - 1
    visit (kk) = 0      
     
    RETURN
END
```

Comment: `call bond (jj)` is a recursive call that calls itself infinite times (or until the stack memory runs out). Also `voisin_logic` should be initialised to `.true.` or `.false.` as the recursive call of `bond(jj)` happens inside a loop based on a condition over `voisin_logic`.

Comment: What compiler are you using?  The gfortran tag is definitely wrong as FOR3414 is not a gfortran error.  We also need a better display of the source code, because what is posted is garbage.

Comment: If you intend the subroutine to be recursive, the solution might be including that keyword in the subroutine declaration.

Comment: In a the most recent revision of the Fortran standard (2018) almost all subprograms are now recursive by default. Thus we will need to know exactly which compiler, which version, and what compilation flags you are using (to check if, for instance, you are imposing an earlier standard)